# ASP.NET Core Web API with Entity Framework : return object with relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

My apologies for my bad English.

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API using Entity Framework. For one of my methods, I want to return an object with all relationships (one to one).

My `UserAccount` class is:

```
[Table("UserAccount")]
public class UserAccount : BaseClass
{
    // Foreign Keys
    [ForeignKey(nameof(UserAccountType))]
    public int UserAccountTypeId { get; set; } 
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Gender))]
    public int GenderId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Truck))]
    public int? TruckId { get; set; }

    // Properties
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Mail { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    // Navigation Properties
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public virtual Gender Gender { get; set; }
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public virtual UserAccountType UserAccountType { get; set; }
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public virtual Truck Truck { get; set; }
}
```

I also use a DTO class :

```
public class UserAccountDto : BaseClassDto
{
    // Foreign Keys
    public int UserAccountTypeId { get; set; }
    public int GenderId { get; set; }
    public int TruckId { get; set; }

    // Properties
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Mail { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    // Linked Objects
    public virtual GenderDto Gender { get; set; }
    public virtual UserAccountTypeDto UserAccountTypes { get; set; }
    public virtual TruckDto Trucks { get; set; }
}
```

I want to receive all relationship object for `Gender`, `UserAccountType` and `Truck`.

My method is :

```
[HttpGet("GetByTruck/{truckId}", Name = "UserAccountByTruckId")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
public async Task<ActionResult<UserAccount>> GetByTruckId(int truckId)
{
    if (truckId <= 0) 
        return BadRequest();

    try
    {
        var userAccounts = await _repository.UserAccount.GetByTruckIdAsync(truckId);
        var userAccountsResult = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<UserAccountDto>>(userAccounts);

        if (userAccountsResult == null) 
            return NotFound();

        return Ok(userAccountsResult);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError($"Something went wrong inside GetById action int UserAccountController : {ex.Message} ");
        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, "Internal Server Error");
    }
}
```

In this method, the property contains all the objects but when I try to map result with the Dto class I lose relationship objects.

So I only have a UserAccount object without the other objects like Gender, UserAccountType or Truck.
This objects become Null.
Is there anybody who can help me?

Thanks

Comment: Hello, at first, I strongly recommend you to use facades or at least repositories to extract code for manipulation with DB from controller actions. To your problem, I see that you are using some kind of mapper (maybe automapper?). What is your mapping profile definition for mapping entities to DTO ?

Comment: try creating a mapping config:
Mapper.CreateMap<UserAccount, UserAccountDto>()
  .ForMember(dto => dto.Gender, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.Gender));

Comment: @SamJ26 I actually use a repository which includes Gender, UserAccountType and Truck.
I also have a mapper file with this `CreateMap<UserAccount, UserAccountDto>();`

Comment: @ranton187 I have a mapping file with this `CreateMap<UserAccount, UserAccountDto>();`. Can you how to use (and where) .ForMember(dto => dto.Gender...)?
Thanks

Comment: @ranton187 Ok... I try this `  CreateMap<UserAccount, UserAccountDto>().ForMember(dto => dto.Genders, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.Gender));` and indeed Gender is no more null. How to do with the other objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @ranton187 you save me !
Hoping that can help others, here is the solution to my problem.
I added this in the mapping config file :

CreateMap<UserAccount, UserAccountDto>()
.ForMember(dto => dto.Genders, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.Gender))
.ForMember(dto => dto.UserAccountTypes, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.UserAccountType))
.ForMember(dto => dto.Trucks, opt =>  opt.MapFrom(x => x.Truck));

Now Gender, UserAccountTypes and Truck objects are no more null.

Thanks to both of you for your fast help !